# is it possible to have a virtual class declaration in a class?

Tags: c++

I'm setting a up an interface for various components of a framework in a personal project, and i've suddenly thought of something that i figured might be useful with an interface. My question is whether this is possible or not:

```
class a
{
public:
    virtual class test = 0;

};

class b : public a
{
public:
    class test
    {
        public:
           int imember;
    };
};

class c : public a
{
public:
    class test
    {
    public:
           char cmember;  // just a different version of the class. within this class
    };
};
```

sort of declaring a virtual class or pure virtual class, that is required to be defined within the derived object, so that you might be able to do something like this:

```
int main()
{
    a * meh = new b();
    a * teh = new c();

    /* these would be two different objects, but have the same name, and still be able  
 to be referred to by an interface pointer in the same way.*/
    meh::test object1;    
    teh::test object2;

    delete meh;
    delete teh;

    return 0;
}
```

msvc++ throws me a bunch of syntax errors, so is there a way to do this, and i'm just not writing it right?

Comment: You can probably achieve this using *Abstract class*

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem. What is your real problem? Because whatever that is, the code above isn't the solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it isn't valid. In any case, C++ has no concept of virtual classes as such. You can probably achieve what you want by holding a pointer to a certain class with only pure virtual methods (although that isn't a requirement):

```
class ITest { /* full of pure virtual methods... maybe. */};

class a
{
public:
    virtual ITest* someFunctionName()=0 ;
private:
    ITest* test_;
};
```

Then you can decide to inherit from a, giving each implementation concrete implementations of `ITest`, or some other approach, such as deciding which implementation to use based on some constructor parameter, for example.

Comment: disappoint ensues... but thanks for the suggestion. I figure what i'm working on is gonna get complicated enough without having to hax it just to get this :/ . i'm sure i can find a different way than virtual classes. anyone know why this *isn't* a feature?

Comment: @FatalCatharsis: Roughly speaking, the `::` scope operator takes a class (or namespace) on the left, while the `.` operator takes a value (object, reference, expression, etc) on the left.  `meh::test` applies `::` to the pointer `meh`. Also, C++ is strongly typed. The static type of the expression `meh::test` would have to be set at compile time. Potentially you could have a dynamic type derived from that, Liskov Substitution allows that, but the mechanism for it is entirely unclear.

Answer (score 0):

The keyword "virtual" merely means "table to dispatch function call.
What you proposed is not part of the language.

But you can approach it in another way, by chaining the object creation to proper virtual calls:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


class a
{
public:
    class test
    {
    public:
        virtual ~test() {} ///< required to have polimorphic behavior
        virtual void hello() const =0;
    };

    virtual test* create_test()=0;
};


class b: public a
{
public:
    class test_b: public a::test
    {
        virtual void hello() const 
        { cout << "this is test_b at " << this << endl; }
    };
    virtual test* create_test() 
    { return new test_b; }
};

class c: public a
{
public:
    class test_c: public a::test
    {
        virtual void hello() const 
        { cout << "this is test_c at " << this << endl; }
    };
    virtual test* create_test() 
    { return new test_c; }
};

int main()
{
    a* pa1 = new b;
    a* pa2 =  new c;

    a::test* p1 = pa1->create_test();
    a::test* p2 = pa2->create_test();

    p1->hello();
    p2->hello();

    delete p2; delete p1;
    delete pa2; delete pa1;
}
```