# Instantiating a class that derives from an interface that's inside another class that derives from an interface... just read to find out

Tags: c++

I asked a while ago [how to use virtual classes in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10241134/is-it-possible-to-have-a-virtual-class-declaration-in-a-class), and to my dismay i learned that you can't. But one user,(namely "Emilio Garavaglia" thanks a bunch), posted a way to get something similar to virtual classes, just with some extra code. however, i'm having some trouble getting what i'm doing to compile. here's the code:

global_defs.h

```
#define Interface class

#define abstract_class class

#define implements : public
```

I_Graphics.h

```
#ifndef I_GRAPHICS_H
#define I_GRAPHICS_H

#include <string>
#include "global_defs.h"

Interface I_Graphics
{
public:
    virtual ~I_Graphics() {};

    virtual void Initialize() = 0;
    virtual void Frame() = 0;
    virtual void Shutdown() = 0;

    class I_Model;

    virtual I_Model * CreateModel() = 0;

};

Interface I_Graphics::I_Model
{
public:
    virtual ~I_Model() {}

    virtual void Initialize(std::string const & filename, std::string const & textureFilename) = 0;
    virtual void * GetVertexBuffer() = 0;
    virtual void * GetIndexBuffer() = 0;
};


#endif
```

Graphics.h

```
#ifndef GRAPHICS_H
#define GRAPHICS_H

#include "global_defs.h"

#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include "I_Graphics.h"

class Graphics implements I_Graphics
{
public:
    Graphics();
    ~Graphics();

    void Initialize();
    void Frame();
    void Shutdown();

    class Model;

    I_Model * CreateModel() {return new Model;}   // <--- compile error here

private:
    std::map <std::string, I_Model *> m_ModelList;
};

class Graphics::Model implements I_Graphics::I_Model
{
public:
    Model();
    ~Model();

    void Initialize(std::string filename, std::string textureFilename);
    void * GetVertexBuffer();
    void * GetIndexBuffer();
};

#endif
```

Graphics.cpp
nothing going here, havn't really started working on the hard part yet, just trying to get the model instantiation to work.

```
#include "Graphics.h"

Graphics::Graphics()
{

}

Graphics::~Graphics()
{
}

void Graphics::Initialize()
{

}

void Graphics::Frame()
{

}

void Graphics::Shutdown()
{

}

Graphics::Model::Model()
{

}

Graphics::Model::~Model()
{
}

void Graphics::Model::Initialize(std::string filename, std::string textureFilename)
{


}

void * Graphics::Model::GetVertexBuffer()
{
    return NULL;
}

void * Graphics::Model::GetIndexBuffer()
{
    return NULL;
}
```

so, as the little comment says, i get an error there saying:

`error C2512: 'Graphics::Model' : no appropriate default constructor available`

when there obviously is a constructor for it in graphics.cpp  . Can someone please explain what the compiler is complaining about here?

EDIT:
not sure if it means anything, but when mousing over the little red squiggle in MSVC, it says, "object of abstract class type Graphics::Model is not allowed" . ...but it doesn't have any pure virtual members, so it's not abstract right?

EDIT:
On the suggestion of Castilho, i declare CreateModel in graphics.h like before, but then defined it in graphics.cpp, and it yielded a much more specific error, but i still don't understand why.

`error C2259: 'Graphics::Model' : cannot instantiate abstract class

1>          due to following members:

1>          'void I_Graphics::I_Model::Initialize(const std::string &,const std::string &)' : is abstract

1>          i_graphics.h(28) : see declaration of 'I_Graphics::I_Model::Initialize'`

Comment: `#define abstract_class class` `#define implements : public ` Why??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the Model class before it is defined. Define the function CreateModel in a separate CPP and it may work.

Comment: oh hah, i found it. the signiture of initialize in the I_Model interface wasn't the same as the one in Model, so it thought the initialize function hadn't been defined in Model, meaning it still had an pure abstract member. thanks for helping me find the actual error :P

Comment: ha, just found the error here myself as well ahaha, missing the const & at the redefinition ;)